# Does reading DBF files from SQL server hamper the actual files?

Tags: sql, performance, dbf

So I read data like this:

1. A view is created on local server which reads local dbf files.
2. I then select data from that view through linked server on the "master" server which I could than insert into some real tables on the master server

Can this corrupt or hamper the performance of the original local .dbf files? The files are used and updated live for another application (not mine).

(I just remembered a possible solution if that would be the case: I could copy the dbf files and then select data from the copies, but that would mean additional .bat or .exe.)

Comment: The job of the server is to totally abstract the underlying storage files from its clients (you), in general use the files are things you simply don't need to concern your self with, the server will manage them itself - its a *server* database, its not like Access or another file based system.

Comment: @AlexK.: Thanks. Just out of curiosity - does that mean that when I read via OPENROWSET (forgot to mention that in the original question), the files are first somehow read into memory and immediately released?

Comment: Its dodgy to think about this in terms of "files", you don't connect to or use the files, you connect to a server. The server sits on the files & manages them in an optimised way ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337525 )